# Rate limits for Big commerce Basic Authentication

Tags: bigcommerce

We build an app that will retrieve information about orders from Big commerce shops. We use Basic Authentication to the Stores API which limits requests to 20,000 per hour. 
The question is: if more than one user will use our app to get information from their shops, will rate limit be 20000 for each shop or 20000 overall?

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Answer (score 0):

The limit is per store. 20k per hour is for some lower plans, plans such as enterprise have unlimited API calls per hour.

Comment: Is there a way to know this rate limit calling a bigcommerce API's endpoint?